# Get highest value from every group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table:
`Id`, `Name`, `Account`, `Date`, `ItemsToSend`

1. I want to group rows by `Name` and `Account`
2. From each group I want to get elements with latest `Date`
3. And display element's `Name`, `Account` and `ItemsToSend`

I managed something like this:

```
select
    Name,
    Account,
    max(Date),
    max(CountItemsSend)
from History
where
    Date = (
        select max(Date)
        from History as p
        where
            p.Account = History.Account
            and p.Name = History.Name
    )
group by
    Name,
    Account
```

I am afraid of `max(Date), max(CountItemsSend)`. I dont think it is ok. After `where` there is only 1 result for each group, so what is the point of `max` use there?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Try using window functions

Comment: "I don't think it is ok".  What do you mean?  That's the purpose of aggregation.  In this case, for each `Name, Account` group, there should only be one `MAX()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need aggregation.  Just:

```
select h.*
from History h
where h.Date = (select max(h2.Date)
                from History h2
                where h2.Account = h.Account and
                      h2.Name = h.Name
               );
```

Comment: I am getting error: `An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to number rows grouped by `name` and `account` and ordered by `date` descending and then select the rows with number equal to 1. These rows are with max `Date` per group and `CountItemsSend` from the same row.

```
SELECT
    t.[Name],
    t.[Account],
    t.[Date],
    t.[CountItemsSend]
FROM (
   SELECT
      [Name],
      [Account],
      [Date],
      [CountItemsSend],
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [Acount] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS Rn
   FROM History
) t
WHERE t.Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A CTE can make this neater.

```
WITH maxDates as
(
    SELECT Name, Account, MAX(Date) as LatestDate
    FROM History
    GROUP BY Name, Account
)

SELECT h.Name, h.Account, h.Date, h.CountItemsSend
FROM History h
INNER JOIN maxDates m
    on m.Name = h.Name and m.Account = h.Account and m.LatestDate = h.Date
```